# Index is always out of range on test in a list of lists

Tags: python-3.x, list, function, indexoutofrangeexception

whenever I try to run this function to test specific values on a list of lists it returns out of index:

```
#this is the list of list running through the functions:

[['District', 'Acton Town', 'Ealing Common', 2], ['Piccadilly', 'Acton Town', 'Ealing Common', 2], ['Piccadilly', 'Ealing Common', 'North Ealing', 2], ['Piccadilly', 'North Ealing', 'Park Royal', 2], ['Piccadilly', 'Park Royal', 'Alperton', 2], ['Piccadilly', 'Alperton', 'Sudbury Town', 3], ['Piccadilly', 'Sudbury Town', 'Sudbury Hill', 2], ['Piccadilly', 'Sudbury Hill', 'South Harrow', 3], ['Piccadilly', 'South Harrow', 'Rayners Lane', 5], ['Metropolitan', 'Rayners Lane', 'West Harrow', 3], ['Metropolitan', 'West Harrow', 'Harrow-on-the-Hill', 2], ['Metropolitan', 'Moor Park', 'Harrow-on-the-Hill', 14], ['Metropolitan', 'Rickmansworth', 'Moor Park', 5], ['Metropolitan', 'Chorleywood', 'Rickmansworth', 4], ['Metropolitan', 'Chalfont & Latimer', 'Chorleywood', 4], ['Metropolitan', 'Amersham', 'Chalfont & Latimer', 4]]

def reverse_if_needed(self):
    """
    Reverse when needed
    """
    final = []
    full_info = self.eliminate_repetition()
    for i in range(len(full_info)):
        if full_info[i][1] != full_info[i-1][2]:
            final.append(self.reverse(full_info[i]))
    return final

def eliminate_repetition(self):
    full_info = self.get_full_route_detail()
    new_full_info = []
    for x in range(len(full_info)):
        if full_info[x][1] != full_info[x - 1][1] and full_info[x][2] != full_info[x - 1][2]:
            new_full_info.append(full_info[x])
    return new_full_info
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? What does self.eliminate_repetition() do and what is the shape of full_info?

Comment: it eliminates positions that are repeated

Answer (score 0):

What does the function `self.reverse(full_info[i])` do?
I replaced this function with `full_info[i]` and I got no error.

Comment: Reverse the positions 1 and 2 in the inner list like ['District', 'Acton Town', 'Ealing Common', 2] will become ['District', 'Ealing Common', 'Acton Town', 2]

Comment: can you provide the function?